# Is there a faster alternative to creating files then deleting them?

Tags: python, xml, python-2.7

I have ~100 XML files that  which I run through a python script. The script makes a subprocess call for each XML file.

I need to edit the XML file based on user input. Because I do not want to edit the original XML file (would show as changes when I push to my repo), I create a new XML file, copy the contents from the original XML file over, and add in the new param and then I make the subprocess call.

My program now takes much longer since I am creating/deleting files. Is there any way I can change my script to speed it up without editing the original XML file?

EDIT: I'm on Windows

Thanks!

Comment: Unless you're just appending to the end of the file, you'd have to 1) read, 2) change, 3) write the file anyway. What exactly are you doing differently…? Alternative angle: depending on the file system you're running, a bare metal file system file copy command many be virtually instantaneous if the file system supports copy-on-write mechanics. That's still rare on the default file system for most OSs though.

Comment: Will the program you're calling accept the file's contents on `stdin`? If it will, you can send it from memory.

Comment: Can you edit the XML tree in memory and pass that to your subprocess call?

Answer (score 0):

One alternative is to use [ramdisk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RAM_drive).  You can copy file to ramdisk, edit it, run script against it and then delete.  In this case, the only I/O operations would be reading a file.

If you're running Linux, you can do:

```
mkdir /mnt/ramdisk
mount -t tmpfs -o size=512m tmpfs /mnt/ramdisk
```

Then use /mnt/ramdisk for your file operations.

If you're running Windows, you can use software such as [ImDisk](http://www.ltr-data.se/opencode.html/#ImDisk) to create ramdisk.

Note: Using ramdisk can reduce I/O cost.  But first of all you need to make sure I/O is the bottleneck of your script performance.  Otherwise it won't help a lot.